# Show user response message flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm registering user and I want to show user a message through `json`. How I'll show. Kindly check if there is any modification need regarding coding as I'm new in flutter.

Thanks.

```
  void _registration() async {
String name = _nameController.text.trim();
String email = _emailController.text.trim();
String password = _passwordController.text.trim();
String phone = _phoneController.text.trim();

if (name.isEmpty) {
  Utils.flushBarErrorMessage("Type your name", context);
} else if (email.isEmpty) {
  Utils.flushBarErrorMessage("Type your email", context);
} else if (!GetUtils.isEmail(email)) {
  Utils.flushBarErrorMessage("Type valid email address", context);
} else if (password.isEmpty) {
  Utils.flushBarErrorMessage("Type your password", context);
} else if (password.length < 6) {
  Utils.flushBarErrorMessage(
      "password can't be less than 6 characters", context);
} else if (phone.isEmpty) {
  Utils.flushBarErrorMessage("Type your phone", context);
} else {
  var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
  if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
      connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
    ApiCall.signUp(name, email, password, phone).then((value) async {
      if (value.statusCode == 200) {
        if (json.decode(value.body)['success'] != null) {
          if (json.decode(value.body)["success"]) {
            RegisterResponse registerResponseModel =
                RegisterResponse.fromJson(json.decode(value.body));

          } else {
            Utils.flushBarErrorMessage(
                json.decode(value.body)["en_message"], context);
            print(json.decode(value.body).toString());
          }
        }
      } else {
        Utils.flushBarErrorMessage('invalid data', context);
        print(json.decode(value.body).toString());
      }
    });
  } else {
    Utils.flushBarErrorMessage("No Internet", context);
  }
}
}
```

My registration Api response

```
{
"success": true,
"en_message": "",
"ar_message": "",
"data": {
    "user": {
        "first_name": "yt",
        "username": "",
        "email": "yat@gmail.com",
        "type": 1,
        "role_id": 4,
        "verification_code": 9141,
        "verified": 0,
        "phone": "123456",
        "updated_at": "2022-07-06T09:56:49.000000Z",
        "created_at": "2022-07-06T09:56:49.000000Z",
        "id": 140,
        "balance": [
            {
                "AED": 0
            }
        ]
    }
},
"status": 200
}
```

My Response Model

```
class RegisterResponse {
  RegisterResponse({
    bool? success,
    String? enMessage,
    String? arMessage,
    Data? data,
    int? status,
  }) {
    _success = success;
    _enMessage = enMessage;
    _arMessage = arMessage;
    _data = data;
    _status = status;
  }

  RegisterResponse.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _success = json['success'];
    _enMessage = json['en_message'];
    _arMessage = json['ar_message'];
    _data = json['data'] != null ? Data.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
    _status = json['status'];
  }

  bool? _success;
  String? _enMessage;
  String? _arMessage;
  Data? _data;
  int? _status;

  RegisterResponse copyWith({
    bool? success,
    String? enMessage,
    String? arMessage,
    Data? data,
    int? status,
  }) =>
      RegisterResponse(
        success: success ?? _success,
        enMessage: enMessage ?? _enMessage,
        arMessage: arMessage ?? _arMessage,
        data: data ?? _data,
        status: status ?? _status,
      );

  bool? get success => _success;

  String? get enMessage => _enMessage;

  String? get arMessage => _arMessage;

  Data? get data => _data;

  int? get status => _status;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['success'] = _success;
    map['en_message'] = _enMessage;
    map['ar_message'] = _arMessage;
    if (_data != null) {
      map['data'] = _data?.toJson();
    }
    map['status'] = _status;
    return map;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your json contains the message you wanted? Or just need to print message   when status code = 200

Comment: I've messages in API regarding registration like email already registered, User is not verified, please verify the user to login ! etc. Like this I want to show user in snackbar.

Comment: It's better to post the json here. Or you can access it by specifying key value but depends on how it structured

Comment: I've posted the response model.

Comment: Which key contains your message?

Comment: `"en_message": "",` oh this is empty. So should now I print here my own message?

Comment: Updated my answer. That was the problem. Please upvote and select the answer

Answer (score 0):

en_message should have a value in response.

Your enMessage is empty, that's why you didn't get any message.

Use this inside snackbar, if content is not null

```
registerResponseModel.enMessage
```

.

Comment: nothing happend

Comment: Where did you executed the code? And are you sure getting the response model data from api

Comment: `RegisterResponse registerResponseModel =
                    RegisterResponse.fromJson(json.decode(value.body));
                print(registerResponseModel.enMessage);` when I print('success') it print but can't get the message from response, as I if entered same email then i got the `snackbar` with text that email is already exist

Comment: Can you post the apiresponse

Comment: updated my with API response.

Comment: Kindly check the code is it valuable or not and where I've to set async?

Comment: I think it's okay.

Comment: Try with wrong credentials in mobile, may be you will get that message. I am not sure.